# App background refresh ios9 swift

Tags: ios, swift, background, ios9

I've been developing an app that uses location services for iOS with swift.  It's been excellent until ios9.  For some reason my app stops running when put in the background, but only on the physical device.  The simulator runs fine in the background.  I am logging stuff via NSLog so I can tell it stops on the device versus the sim.

Yes I have the info.plist set.  Yes I have background capabilities turned on.  This really did work in iOS8 but for some reason with 9 the app stops executing in the background.

I have background refresh turned on in the settings, and my app is set to always request location updates, which is also turned on in the phone's settings.

I am at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening is so I am guessing there may have been some code changes with xcode7 and/or ios9 that I need to implement.

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Rob

Answer (score 2):

So it appears Apple requires a new thing in iOS9 :

```
allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

This is for the location manager.

My final code looks like :

```
    // this is needed for ios9 to get the location even when it's backgrounded
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Comment: Cheers bro, you saved me

Comment: Bit stupid how if you didnt know this, and dont keep your app updated, ios 9 users cant use this function!

Comment: Yes this was very frustrating.  Drove me nuts for a week !!